# Bookmarklet - on right click?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to fire a bookmarklet on a right click command or is this browser dependant?

So, I have a bookmarklet which gathers information, I want a user to be able to right click on any page and it opens the bookmarklet

Comment: Missing `oncontextmenu`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely impossible. The code in a bookmarklet doesn't exist in a page until a person clicks on the bookmarklet.

Look into userscripts for what you want. They are nearly as simple as bookmarklets, but they run every time a page loads. Some browsers like Chrome support userscripts natively. Others like Firefox requires an addon like Greasemonkey. The other option is using or creating an add-on.

The code in your userscript might look like

```
document.oncontextmenu = function() { // on "right click"...
  // some code
  return false; // optional - suppress the native context menu. not advisable for entire document.
}
```

Comment: I understand that, but, my question is, can a bookmarklet be opened on a right click command

Comment: Darren, what do the first two words in my answer mean to you?

Comment: Nothing is impossible. The second line of your answer completely ignores the question. "The code in a bookmarklet doesn't exist in a page until a person clicks on the bookmarklet." Well, obviously! And after investigating further I think it can be done using a browser-extension which I agree is different to a bookmarklet but still will accomplish the task at hand. Although I could be wrong!

Comment: Not only did I give you the correct answer, but I also suggested alternative solutions. I even gave you code to solve your problem. But what do you do? You simply repeat your question; the question I already answered. Then you tell me that you "think it can be done using a browser-extension". Maybe you don't know this, but "add-on" is another word for extension, and I already said, "The other option is using or creating an add-on". BTW, the second line of my answer ignores NOTHING. It explains WHY it is IMPOSSIBLE to right click on a page to execute a bookmarklet (without using an extension).